# What is "Google Play Android Developer" in Google API's Project

Tags: android, google-api

I am really confused on why there is a project named `Google Play Android Developer` in my projects listing. I have developed a really simple app which I created a project for but I don't know what `Google Play Android Developer` project is for. When do I use this?

P.S. Sorry if this is the wrong place to post. I couldn't find a better place

Comment: give proof picture

Answer (score -2):

U can reffer Android developer console ;

[Click this link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview)